# KDE: Discover can't fetch updates

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I just converted my Ubuntu 19.10 system to Kubuntu by installing the KDE Plasma 5 packages, but for some reason Discover has issues fetching updates (just spins its wheels and won't even try). If I attempt to update everything via the CLI (sudo apt update), everything works out fine there and shows that I'm updated but Discover still has problems. Have I forgotten to install a package or two, maybe?

Comment: Discover may take much longer than the command-line. How did you do the conversion? How did you decide on "the KDE Plasma 5 packages"? Knowing that would help.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a special scenario where this error can happen. When you have initially installed Ubuntu without a desktop environment, Ubuntu's netplan configuration tool will use `networkd` instead of `NetworkManager` by default. If you then later manually install a desktop environment, some graphical tools such as KDE's Discover will fail because they expect a working `NetworkManager`. Check the netplan configuration file to see what your system is using:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

If it says `renderer: networkd`, this is likely the cause. Change it to `renderer: NetworkManager` and apply the new setting with `sudo netplan apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. open terminal
2. Run command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install plasma-discover
   ```

And this will work because I was also facing the same issue.

Actually this command will overwrite the dependency of Discover and if there is any missing dependency then this command will add them to fix the problem for fetching and installing apps or to update them.

I am using Kubuntu 19.10